# configure many to many relationship in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

So following this example:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

I have a Student class:

```
public class Student
    {
        public Student() { }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

and a Course class

```
public class Course
    {
        public Course()
        {
            this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

They have Many-to-Many relationship which is configured this way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

       modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasMany<Course>(s => s.Courses).WithMany(c => c.Students).Map(c =>
        {
            c.MapLeftKey("Student_id");
            c.MapRightKey("Course_id");
            c.ToTable("StudentAndCourse");
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

I have created the models and tables myself and map to them. So far so good. The problem is I do not need the collection of related Students to my courses. In other words when I get my courses they are coming with their related Students. I need the Students with the assigned Courses but when I get the courses through my repo, I need only them.

I tried to remove the Students collection from my Course class but was enable to fix the mapping. I am not experienced with EF and any help with working example will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the students shouldn't be loaded unless specifically requested (making it an eager/lazy loading issue); or there shouldn't be a students nav property in your class, only in your data model?

Comment: well, I have two repos - for Students and Courses. When I say give me all Students from the Student Repo, I need all students with their courses. But when I say give me all courses from Courses repo - I need only the courses ... I do not need the students in any case.

Comment: So, to rephrase (just to be sure): The navigational property needs to be there, but you want to choose when it is automatically loaded and when it is left empty?

Comment: Oddly enough, your code snippet hints that lazy loading is already set up (the `ICollection`s are `virtual`). Can you show the code in the repository that is supposed to load the courses *without* the students? I'd expect the nav prop to be empty, based on what you've currently shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`WithMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696481%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method which does not require navigation property for related entities:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
       .HasMany(s => s.Courses)
       .WithMany()
       .Map(c =>
    {
        c.MapLeftKey("Student_id");
        c.MapRightKey("Course_id");
        c.ToTable("StudentAndCourse");
    });
```